# UTF8 without BOM ends up in ANSI

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

With the code like below I ended it up with ANSI encoding. any ideas?

```
Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\text.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, utf8WithoutBom);
    sw.Write("sfsdfsdfsdf");
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: "sfsdfsdfsdf" in UTF-8 is ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain text files do not save what encoding they're in anywhere, there's no format specification for where that meta information should be stored. All you have in the end is a file with a bunch of bytes in it. It's up to any application how it interprets those bytes and how it finds out what encoding the file is in.

UTF-8 with ASCII-only characters is exactly identical to an ASCII encoded file is exactly identical to an ANSI encoded file or "Latin-1" encoded file. There's no difference in the raw bytes. If an application identifies that file as ANSI that's just as valid as any of the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you're saying plain text could be represented with ASCII then it's ANSI encoding even when I explicit specify it as UTF-8 encoding? I just tried to add some UTF-8 characters inside the plain text then it's UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: The ASCII character set happens to be identical to the first 128 UTF8 character codes and the first 128 ANSI character codes.

Comment: @Lys Yes, plain ASCII-only text saved in UTF-8 is indistinguishable from ASCII or ANSI. The application you're opening the file in is simply mis-identifying it (well, not really, since assuming it's ANSI is perfectly valid). Maybe you'll want to read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)